# Html clickable images; org mode, org-mode-info or readtheorg

Tags: org-mode, read-the-docs

So I'm using org-mode html export functionality and it works perfectly fine; especially with either of these great [themes](https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes)!

My main concern is merely about images. While i was installing *mu4e*, there was an [image that i couldn't preview](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+email/mu4e/README.html#notifications), which made me kinda hacked it *(in a personal project)* see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:

1. creating a **[js script](https://github.com/hasan-sh/AI_notes_emacs/blob/master/imageModal.js)** that gets all images in a page and creates a
   modal containing the clicked image.
2. *(run only once)* having a **[python script](https://github.com/hasan-sh/AI_notes_emacs/blob/master/appendModal.py)** that appends the script tag to all nested html files in a dir.

This now works fine and the modals can now be toggled, however, and as you may see, it's hacky and pretty useful at the same time. So it would be nice if it could be added to `org-info-js`! Any suggestions?

```
I'm listing this question/suggestion here, because the issues section is disabled on org-mode's [github][1] page.
```